# reduce ndarray dimesion to max nonzero index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a large ndarray and I want to reduce it's first dimension, replacing it with the highest nonzero index number of that dimension.  For example, if [:,0,0] is (0,1,6,0,0), I would like to [0,0] of the new array to equal "3".  I've run ndarray.nonzero, but I'm unsure of where to go from there.  Any help appreciated.  A little code below to get started:

```
import numpy as np
myary = np.random.randint(0,4,(10,5,5))
newary = np.nonzero(myary)
```

Answer (score 1):

## "Mask, flip and argmax" solution

You can still use argmax for another purpose: getting the first `True`s along the flipped subarrays.

#### Condensed version

```
def last_nonzero(arr):
    return arr.shape[-1] - np.argmax(np.flip(arr>0, axis=-1), axis=-1) - 1

last_nonzero(np.array([[0, 1, 6, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0]]))
# > array([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

#### Explanation

Just generating sparse data:

```
import numpy as np
myary = np.random.randint(0,2, (4,3,2))*np.random.randint(0,20,(4, 3, 2))
# > array([[[18,  5,  3, 17],
#           [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
#           [ 0, 14,  0, 17]],
#          [[ 0,  0, 10,  8],
#           [ 0, 18, 13,  0],
#           [ 7,  3,  0,  0]]])
```

We can now mask for `values > 0` to get a **boolean array**, then **flip** it along the last axis:

```
flipped_mask = np.flip(myary>0, axis=-1)
# > array([[[ True,  True,  True,  True],
#           [False, False, False, False],
#           [ True, False,  True, False]],
#          [[ True,  True, False, False],
#           [False,  True,  True, False],
#           [False, False,  True,  True]]])
```

Now we can take the **argmax** along the last axis. It will give us the index of the first `True` in each subarray of the mask.

```
max_mask = np.argmax(flipped_mask, axis=-1)
# > array([[0, 0, 0],
#          [0, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Finally, since we processed the flipped version, we must "flip back" the indices by substracting them to the length of the subarrays (minus 1 because of zero-indexing):

```
last_nonzero = myary.shape[-1] - max_mask - 1
# > array([[3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

#### Observation

If a "subarray" is full of zeros only, this solution will return the last index of the subarray.

```
last_nonzero(np.array([[0,1,2,3,0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))
# > array([3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm not looking for the maximum value along that axis.  Rather, I'm looking for the largest *index* of non-zero values along that axis.  So, for [0, 5, 1, 0], it would be 2 (corresponding to the 3rd element:1).

Comment: @AlexanderShenkin Thanks, I get it now. I just provided a detailed solution.